# A collective noun for a group of spaceships

Tags: spaceships, language

A shrewdness of apes, an unkindness of ravens, a murder of crows...I wonder how to call a collection of spaceships often seen in the proximity to my planet that is apparently a fruit of a particular kind of alien intellect in every occasion?

Comment: Group? Swarm? School? Pack? Herd? Squadron? Fleet? Flotilla? Wing? You may want to take the [tour] and become familiar with the purpose and bylaws of this site. As it is, your question is primarily opinion based, and will most likely be closed for this reason.

Comment: An intimidation of warships, a curiosity of exploration vessels, a profit opportunity of tourists. AlexP beat me to it.

Comment: AlexP, is a school in a school of fish opinion based? a pride in a pride of lions matter of preference?

Comment: Well, yes, because there is no empirical, objective reasoning behind them being called that.

Comment: Welcome to the site @VadumR As Alex mentioned SE sites have rules beyond a standard forum/discussion board.  The site is all about specific questions with specific answers.  Questions are expected to have a "best" answer which means we need criteria to help us decide which answer is better than another.  Check out the site and check out the [help] and [tour].  [This bit is particularly useful.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 10):

My suggestions are:

- Fleet
- Convoy
- Flotilla
- Navy
- Squadron

They could all be used to describe a normal vehicle and are often used for spaceships in science fiction.

Answer (score 4):

A [constellation of satellites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_constellation). Almost everything is a satellite of something, so the ships wouldn't even need to move to a parking orbit first...

Answer (score 3):

- Menace
- Blossoming
- Fruiting
- Gathering
- Convention
- Tangle

Questions that engender list answers aren't really on topic here, aside from the fact that it's all opinion.  That being said, I tried to come up with names that express the intelligence of the ships (not just inanimate objects) as well as their interconnectiveness.

Comment: Menace it is. "A friendly menace of ships skirted the atmosphere."

Comment: +1 since "alien intellect" is all we have to go on. That said you probably should add another list to cover the "alien" part. Like enigma, mystery, etc.

Comment: @VilleNiemi I figured I'd let others come up with different names.  Didn't want to spend too much time on a question I knew would get closed.  But I'm glad one of mine was helpful to the OP.

Comment: Yeah, IMHO people tend to focus too much on the criteria for chosen answer when in a site like world building the upvote criteria of useful/helpful is, again IMHO, more practical and important.